# Error: Cannot find SourceControlToken with name GitHub on Azure Devops Portal

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-bicep

I have an Azure Bicep file which creates an Azure Function App and Deploys code from a repository to that function app. When I run this file locally, it runs perfectly but when I run it on azure devops portal it throws the following error: **Cannot find SourceControlToken with name GitHub on Azure Devops Portal**.

Attaching the code: The below code will create the function app but fails to deploy the code from github on devops portal. But it works locally well

```
resource azureFunction 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-12-01' = {
  name: pFunctionAppName
  location: pLocation
  kind: 'functionapp'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: pServerFarmId
    httpsOnly: true
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: 'python|3.10'
      alwaysOn: true
      ftpsState: 'FtpsOnly'
      minTlsVersion: '1.2'
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${pStorageAccountName};AccountKey=${listKeys(pStorageAcountId, '2022-09-01').keys[0].value}'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${pStorageAccountName};AccountKey=${listKeys(pStorageAcountId, '2022-09-01').keys[0].value}'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE'
          value: toLower(pFunctionAppName)
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~4'
        }
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
          value: azAppInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey
        }
        {
          name: 'APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING'
          value: azAppInsights.properties.ConnectionString
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
          value: 'python'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource sourcecontrol 'Microsoft.Web/sites/sourcecontrols@2022-09-01' = {
  parent: azureFunction
  name: 'web'
  properties: {
    repoUrl: pRepoUrl
    branch: pBranchName
    isManualIntegration: true
  }
}
```

In the azure devops portal I can see in the Service Connections the reference to the github account.

Answer (score 0):

When I used your code, Even I received the same error code as yours, Refer below:-

[image]

I tried below code and used az cli task to deploy bicep file with Azure Function like below:-

**my func.bicep code:-**

```
param appName string
param location string
param storageAccountName string

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-04-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
}

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-02-01' = {
  name: '${appName}'
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp'
  sku: {
    name: 'Y1'
    tier: 'Dynamic'
  }
}

resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
  name: appName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp'
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
          value: 'python'
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccount.name};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccount.id, '2021-04-01').keys[0].value};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource functionAppName_web 'Microsoft.Web/sites/sourcecontrols@2020-12-01' = {
  parent: functionApp
  name: 'web'
  properties: {
    repoUrl: 'https://github.com/username/funchttp'
    branch: 'main'
    isManualIntegration: true
  }
}
```

**My YAML script:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'subscription (xxxx-xxx-44d6-xxxd-e2b6xxxx)'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az deployment group create --resource-group siliconrg9 --template-file func.bicep --parameters appName=siliconfunc906 location=eastus storageAccountName=valleystrg906'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***HTTPTrigger with Function app deployed successfully, Refer below:-***

[image]

**Add https://portal.azure.com as CORS in Function app to run it on Portal:-**

[image]

Comment: I'll try this and let you know

Comment: Hey, I went through the script that you posted and compared with my mine. I already have the service plan and storage account created so I just pass their values. My azure function is getting created but the deployment with source control fails. Both the codes are similar its just I'm using existing resources. Is there anything special you are doing in the devops portal with service connections?

Comment: Can you elaborate more what exact changes you did because its not working for me

Comment: Does your service connection have Owner or atleast contributor role assigned at the Subscription or resource group level at which you're deploying your function app? I am using default Azure subscription as my service connection which has owner role at the subscription level

Comment: I created a service connection as in the Settings > Service Connections with reference to the resource group and the pipeline was not able to access it directly and in the yml file I'm using that reference name to get the resource group. You have defined subscription like this azureSubscription: 'subscription (xxxx-xxx-44d6-xxxd-e2b6xxxx)'. Did you put in the subscription id over there?

Comment: I have contributor's access thats the most I can get because of company's resources.

Comment: I even tried defining this azureSubscription: 'subscription (xxxx-xxx-44d6-xxxd-e2b6xxxx)' part the way you did just added my subscription id. It worked locally but in devops portal same error

Comment: I even gave the project access as a contributor at subscription level. earlier it was at resource group level still not working

Comment: @nirajparte I have selected the Subscription like this - https://i.imgur.com/lxDo50N.png I Selected the default one, I did not create any new Service connection. It might pop up for a log in just log in with your account and it will be selected

Comment: Hi Siddhesh. I tried the above way so sent in the screenshot. Pointed the azureSubscription to the default one. I asked for authorization too and did that but still facing the same error

Comment: Hope the repository url you're using is correct?

Comment: should I use the one with the .git at the end or the one present in browser?

Comment: No need of git use the url from the browser itself..

Comment: hey. I tried both ways still the same error. The url is right because the code works locally but doesnt work in devops portal